# Javascript Track page scroll depth on webpage load after 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% only if a user waits for 2seconds

Tags: javascript

To fire a console.log if a user scrolls on a webpage 25% and waits for 2 seconds or more. Similarly fire 50% scroll after a user scrolls a webpage 50% and waits for 2 seconds and similarly for 75% and 100%.
For example a user scrolls directly to 50% and waits there for 2 seconds then fire only 50% and not 25%. And also when the user scrolls to 100% quickly without 2 secs halt and then goes back to top do not fire any console.log as user has'nt waited for 2 secs. Pls help in adding this 2 seconds halt and then firing the console.log,

I did this using Javascript it is working but now how to add 2 seconds ?

```
var maxScrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var percentageObj = {};
var percentagesArr = [25,50,75,100];
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    var scrollVal = this.scrollY;
    for(var i =0; i<percentagesArr.length;i++){
        var currentPercentage = percentagesArr[i];
        var scrollPercentage = parseInt((maxScrollHeight/100) * currentPercentage);
        if(scrollVal >= scrollPercentage && !window.percentageObj[scrollPercentage.toString()]){
            console.log("scrolled past - " + currentPercentage.toString() + "%");
            window.percentageObj[scrollPercentage.toString()] = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `setTimeout` to delay logging and `clearTimeout` whenever page percentage changes:

```js
var maxScrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var percentagesArr = [25,50,75,100];
const showed = {};
let timeout;
let previousPercentage;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    var scrollVal = this.scrollY;
    var scrollPercentage = Math.round(scrollVal / maxScrollHeight * 100);
    let currentPercentage = 0;
    let i = 0;
    while(percentagesArr[i] <= scrollPercentage) {
      currentPercentage = percentagesArr[i++];
    }
    if (previousPercentage !== currentPercentage) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = currentPercentage !== 0 && !showed[currentPercentage]
          ? setTimeout(() => {
              console.log(currentPercentage);
              showed[currentPercentage] = true;
            }, 2000)
          : null;
        previousPercentage = currentPercentage;
    }
});

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  maxScrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 500vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

#container div {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#p25 {
 top: calc(25% * 4/5);
}

#p50 {
 top: calc(50% * 4/5);
}

#p75 {
 top: calc(75% * 4/5);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="p25">25%</div>
  <div id="p50">50%</div>
  <div id="p75">75%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i transpile this to es5 will that be okay.

Comment: @ marzelin, perfect one small thing if i scroll to the bottom and stayed for 2 secs,100% is fired good then again i went to top and come back to the bottom and stayed for 2secs i see 100 is again firing. Can we make sure once a console.log for 100 or 50 or 75 or 25 is fired then do not fire it again, meaning if console.log for 25 is fired even if i repeat and stayed on the page for 25% i dont want 25 to fire again. but i want other to fire like if i stayed for 2 sec on 50 let 50 fire or 100 fire. but once it is fired then even if i repeat it it shouldnt

Comment: @Amindh remove percentages from the array after logging (I've updated the example)

Comment: update: after a bit of thinking I've noticed that removing an item has a flaw. It's better to flag it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxScrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var percentageObj = {};
var percentagesArr = [25,50,75,100];
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    var scrollVal = this.scrollY;
    for(var i =0; i<percentagesArr.length;i++){
        var currentPercentage = percentagesArr[i];
        var scrollPercentage = parseInt((maxScrollHeight/100) * currentPercentage);
        let currentTop = window.scrollY;
        if(scrollVal >= scrollPercentage && !window.percentageObj[scrollPercentage.toString()]){
            setTimeout((currentTop)=>{
                if(currentTop === window.scrollY){
                    console.log("scrolled past - " + currentPercentage.toString() + "%");
                    window.percentageObj[scrollPercentage.toString()] = true;
                }
            },2000)

        }
    }
});
```

try this.